# Django admin TemplateSyntaxError / TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/

Tags: django, templates, django-admin, django-templates, syntax-error

I've just updated django to version 1.2.4 but, having taken the normal steps with installing the admin, i'm getting a TemplateSyntaxError:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/

Caught TemplateDoesNotExist while rendering: admin/base.html
```

So a superuser has been created, i've installed the app, run syncdb. My urls page is as follows:

```
[...]
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # admin enabled
     (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
     (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
[...]
```

<del>In addition if I follow the paths for the admin media e.g. `http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css`</del>

I get: `Permission denied: /static/admin/css/base.css` - fixed this, but same error loading admin remains

**Update**

OK so it now works, by putting the admin templates inside my normal template dir.. but I assume this is a bad idea, but it perhaps implies it might simply be an issue with permissions or paths?

**Update**

Could this be a permissions issue? What would I want to CHMOD these to?

```
pwd /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin

Adam-Gambles-MacBook-Air:admin adamgamble$ ls -al
total 168
drwxr-xr-x  26 root  admin   884 17 Mar 12:27 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  admin   136 17 Mar 12:27 ..
-rw-------   1 root  admin   268 18 Mar  2008 404.html
-rw-------   1 root  admin   502 18 Mar  2008 500.html
-rw-------   1 root  admin  1095  4 May  2010 actions.html
-rw-------   1 root  admin   347 23 Aug  2008 app_index.html
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  admin   102 17 Mar 12:27 auth
-rw-------   1 root  admin  3605 10 Oct 02:59 base.html
[...ETC...]
```

**PROBLEM FIXED**

Involved reinstalling django, and starting a new project. Dissatisfying result, but thanks for helping out!

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to load?

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/admin/` : now works, but see update, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Check that `django.contrib.admin` is added in the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings. If it's not there, then the admin templates directory, `django/contrib/admin/templates`, won't be added to the list of template directories, and you'll be getting the `TemplateDoesNotExist` error.

Additionally, make sure the `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` is added to `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` settings. That's the actual loader that knows that any `templates/` directory in the root of any installed application package should be used for template discovery.

Comment: I know this is far fetched, but maybe you accidentally omitted a comma separator for the list items somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in django static files like js scripts or css and images are served by a different handler. It seems you did not served the URLs that starts with '^static' then the application may not find them.
I advise you serve them with an additional line in the url.py:

```
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': '/path/to/static/files'}),
```

And try to access the CSS from its URI. If you're able to do so, then also the template should be correctly rendered.

... but again, the error says template rendering error. Did you follow the base installation procedure?
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: Ah have just made that change, but the template still isn't loading, i.e. I can now access base.css ..any ideas?

Comment: Usually the admin site has all the templates in place (they are stored in the django installation directory). If you followed the procedure step by step you should not have problems. If you have still problems then may be some of the directories in the installation of django have restricted access.

Comment: Did you add the default urls?:from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

Comment: Yeh i'll keep having a look over my settings, i've realized if I symlinked the admin templates to my template dir then it would work, but that isn't good practise I assume/ shouldn't have to do that??

Comment: yep `from django.conf.urls.defaults import * ` is at the top of urls.py

Comment: mmmm... pretty sure it should work WITHOUT that turnaround :D what what the heck. Strange thou, usually when something is not found (the template) it's because in the settings.py something is missing.

Comment: It may help if you'd post the settings.py alongside the urls.py

Comment: I guess you also added "django.contrib.admin" to your INSTALLED_APPS setting. Just checking the plug is inserted...

Comment: OK so it now works, by putting the admin templates inside my normal template dir.. but I assume this is a bad idea, but it implies it might be an issue with permissions right?

Comment: It is a possibility, yes. But usually django install itself without such issues I had similar problems with my templates over my directories.

Comment: What kind of OS do you have? And did you installed from source code or using yum or similar?

Comment: My only guess (without the code I can't do better) is to install it using sudo access

Comment: I did, can't for the life of me work it out, its been fine in the past , may just trying mkaing a new django app & seeing if that works!

Comment: Ah no sorry, just saying thats the version im on for reference ;) thanks v much for the help though btw

Answer (score 1):

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/doc/

this means you missed a prerequisite outlined earlier: either the docutils package wasn't installed with

```
pip install docutils
```

or the

```
django.contrib.admindocs
```

package wasn't added to the `INSTALLED_APPS` variable in `settings.py`.